# Is there any quick way to select attribute key value pair (e.g. id="mytest" in <input id="mytest"/>) in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there any way that I can select the attribute key value pair for tag?
For example,

```
<input id="test" type="text"/>
```

I just want to select **id="test"** for quick edit or delete, how can I do that?

Comment: depends where you are? if you ar on it, just do `viW` or `ciW` or `diW`

Comment: When I in the id="test", **viW**  or else, will just edit **=**, not entire the **id="test"**

Comment: I usually just `d2f"` or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
nnoremap <silent> µ @=search('id="', 'ze') > 0 ? 'lvi"<c-g>' : ''<cr>
```

you'll end up in [`Select-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#Select%2dmode), the content of the `id` tag being selected. From the select-mode, it easy to delete (with `<del>` key), or to replace (just type in the new content). If you prefer to simplify the deletion with `x`, and if you don't care about typing `s` before replacing, you can stay in visual mode instead. In that case, remove the `<c-g>` part of the mapping.

However, it only works with double-quoted strings. For any kind of string, you'll need to extract the quote character used:

```
nnoremap <silent> µ @=search('id=[''"]', 'ze') > 0 ? 'lvi'.getline('.')[col('.')-1].'<c-g>' : ''<cr>
```

If you want to be able to continue jumping, then use a non-printable character for the key binding, and add mappings for the other modes.

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-j> @=search('id=[''"]', 'ze') > 0 ? 'lvi'.getline('.')[col('.')-1].'<c-g>' : ''<cr>
" vmap will work in visual and in select mode; 
vmap     <silent> <c-j> <c-\><c-n><c-j>
" you may want to support the insert-mode as well
imap     <silent> <c-j> <c-\><c-n><c-j>
```

Note: We cannot use [`:map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap%2d%3cexpr%3e) because it prevents cursor from moving correctly, hence the use of [`@=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%40%3d)

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you are at the beginning of the line:

```
WviW
```

- `W` to jump to next WORD
- `viW` to visually select current WORD

But visual selection is often not needed in Vim (it is one of its strength) so you could simply do:

```
diW
```

to delete the current WORD, or:

```
ciW
```

to change it, or:

```
yiW
```

to yank it.

See `:help W`, `:help WORD`, `:help operator`, `:help iW`.

Comment: That's not work for select entire **id='test'**, thank you all the same.

Comment: @symphony you seem to have `=` in your `iskeyword` list. That's why it isn't working. have a look at it with `:set iskeyword?`. For more information look at `:h iskeyword` (Note: This may be the right thing for you, we don't know).

Comment: @symphony did you use uppercase `W` or lowercase `w`?

Comment: @romainl, I just use "W", but it only work when my position is before **id**

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, I just do **:set iskeyword-==**, it still doesnot work .

Comment: dumb comment from me. a capital `W` doesn't care about `iskeyword`. However capital `W` should work. What does `:verbose map W` say? does the behaviour still exist if you start vim without plugins and your vimrc?

Comment: @symphony, with the cursor on the first character of your sample line, where is the cursor after you press `w`? After you press `W`?